# Android bold fragment of textview text

Tags: java, android, string

I want to be able to bold a placeholder of my textview text that is `db.getGroupTitleByExtNoteOrder(noteItemList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getNoteOrder())`

Here is what I have tried:

```
HtmlCompat.fromHtml(String.format(fragment.getString(R.string.this_is_base_note), db.getGroupTitleByExtNoteOrder(noteItemList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getNoteOrder()) != null ? " " + db.getGroupTitleByExtNoteOrder(noteItemList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getNoteOrder()) : ""), 0));
```

OR changed the end of this code like this (nothing changed):

```
HtmlCompat.fromHtml(String.format(fragment.getString(R.string.this_is_base_note), db.getGroupTitleByExtNoteOrder(noteItemList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getNoteOrder()) != null ? " " + db.getGroupTitleByExtNoteOrder(noteItemList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getNoteOrder()) : ""), HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
```

This string resource looks like this:

```
<string name="this_is_base_note">This is base note of group<b>%1$s</b>. It cannot be deleted individually but with the rest of the group.</string>
```

Unfortunately my placeholder is not bold. How to solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea can be to use the SpannableString.

First of all you have to split your string in two different string resources

```html
<string name="this_is_base_note_part1">This is base note of group </string>
<string name="this_is_base_note_part2">. It cannot be deleted individually but with the rest of the group.</string>
```

Then you can get your strings, and compose the entire string:

```kotlin
val partOne = getString(R.string.this_is_base_note_part1)
val partTwo = getString(R.string.this_is_base_note_part2)
val stringToBeBolded = db.getGroupTitleByExtNoteOrder(noteItemList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getNoteOrder()) != null ? " " + db.getGroupTitleByExtNoteOrder(noteItemList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getNoteOrder()) : "")

val entireString = partOne + stringToBeBolded + partTwo
```

Now you are ready to create your SpannableString:

```kotlin
val spannable = SpannableString(entireString)
val startBold = partOne.length
val endBold = startBold + stringToBeBolded.length
spannable.setSpan(StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), startBold, endBold, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
```

Now you can set your spannable into your TextView

```kotlin
textview.text = spannable
```

Comment: Yes that's it but with a little of pondering ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you can break the `TextView` into separate sections, you can accomplish this by `xml`

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Bold Text"
android:textStyle="bold" />
```

or you can do it programmatically

```
textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD)
```

Comment: Thank you for your involement but I can't vote for your answer because of my new account :(